# Написание "не" с причастием

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия

***Не***задействованный или **не** задействованный в мероприятиях: как пишется?

Comment: С причастием, Вы хотели сказать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть зависимое слово: не задействованный(где?)в мероприятиях. Следовательно, раздельно.

Если бы это было причастие на -мый, нужно было бы уточнить, где стоит оборот - перед определяемым словом или после него. Перед определяемым словом причастие превратилось бы в прилагательное и писалось бы слитно: Несгибаемая в локте рука, но: рука, не сгибаемая в локте.

Answer (score 1):

**ЗАДЕЙСТВОВАННЫЙ** *(прич. страд. от **задействовать***)

*Задействованный* — это ***полное*** причастие, а с полными причастиями частица "не" пишется слитно, если у этого причастия нет пояснительных слов.
[**НЕ с причастиями**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)

Например:
[Из инструкции] *Не допускать **незадействованный** и **незащищённый** персонал на место разлива.*
***Незадействованный*** энергетический резерв России; **незадействованный** участник.

В Вашем случае при полном причастии есть пояснительное слово, поэтому частица "не" пишется раздельно.

Например:
*Итак, появляется новый, ранее **не задействованный*** (в чём?) ***в истории*** персонаж — полицейский.
***Не задействованный*** (когда?) ***вовремя*** энергетический резерв России; **не задействованный** (в чём?) ***в мероприятиях*** участник.

Answer (score 0):

•   сгибаемый - слово на -мый. Образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида "сгибать". Тогда по правилу "сгибаемый" в зависимости от контекста может быть и страдательным причастием, и прилагательным.Слова на -мый, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, в зависимости от контекста могут быть и страдательными причастиями, и прилагательными. Причастием - при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже (творительного действующего лица или творительного орудия). При других формах пояснительных слов или без пояснительных слов - переходит в прилагательное и, следовательно, подчиняются общим для прилагательных правилам написания частицы НЕ (теряет значение страдательности, значение времени и приобретает качественное значение).

Несгибаемая в локте рука; рука, несгибаемая в локте; никем не сгибаемая рука (прилагательное).
Не сгибаемая мною рука (причастие).

Comment: Я имела в виду следующее примечание:"Иногда при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами после определяемого существительного, например: предприятия, не подведомственные тресту (в условиях обособления конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту); ср.: шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле – черты, не свойственные нашей молодежи".
http://www.old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77 Здесь тоже структура  приближена к причастному обороту после определяемого слова